# How to get the SHA of the branch merged from in a github action workflow push?

Tags: merge, github-actions, pull-request, sha

I wonder if it is possible to get the sha from the branch *merged from* in a github action workflow? I have a github action workflow push event like where I can get the sha of the commit to the branch merged to (here master), but would like to know the branch merged from.

```
name: Merge PR
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  check:
    run: echo "Merge sha ${{ github.sha }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

To extract the branch merged from, you can use the GitHub REST API to fetch information about the pull request corresponding to the push event.

```
name: Merge PR

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Get PR Number
    id: pr_number
    run: echo "::set-output name=number::${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}"

  - name: Get Branch Merged From
    id: branch_merged_from
    run: |
      PR_NUMBER="${{ steps.pr_number.outputs.number }}"
      API_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls/${PR_NUMBER}"
      BRANCH_MERGED_FROM=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" "$API_URL" | jq -r '.head.ref')
      echo "::set-output name=branch_merged_from::${BRANCH_MERGED_FROM}"
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  - name: Display Information
    run: |
      echo "Merged SHA: ${{ github.sha }}"
      echo "Merged From Branch: ${{ steps.branch_merged_from.outputs.branch_merged_from }}"
```

`
Give proper read permissions on PR and Repository meta data.